# Xelatex compilation with command lines

Tags: xetex, eps

I used to integrate `.eps` files into my xelatex documents.

Now, I changed my MacBook, I installed the MacTeX distribution and made it up-to-date on Mavericks, but it does not seem to work any more through the terminal with the command line `xelatex Exemple.tex`. The error message is :

```
"** WARNING ** Could not open conversion result "/var/folders/bx/4ff4rxt95qv5ctn3khqg14zr0000gn/T//xdvipdfmx.61da52e17e1b052d456b3f10b34e2a1d" for image "./Fig7_Slab_dif3_234568_12_16X.eps". Why?
** WARNING ** pdf: image inclusion failed for "Fig7_Slab_dif3_234568_12_16X.eps".
** WARNING ** Failed to read image file: Fig7_Slab_dif3_234568_12_16X.eps
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PSfile (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(88.9365, 471.21)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "PSfile="Fig7_Slab_dif3_234568_12_16X.eps" urx=454.29529 ury=246""
```

Surprisingly, it still works fine if I use TexShop and the "compilation" button...

Could anyone bring me some help?

PS : here is my minimal example :

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
blabla
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Fig7_Slab_dif3_234568_12_16X.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `xelatex Exemple.tex` works then `Exemple.tex` is either in the current directory or in the *TeX* input path. The `.eps` file needs to be either in the current directory or in the "xdvipdfmx* input path. I don't know what that second one is, so it would be best to have the figure in the current directory when running from the command line. It's possible TeXShop's current directory is not the same as your command line's.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I ensured that Exemple.tex and my .eps file were in the same directory, so that it is not the problem... There must be something that TexShop makes differently that my command line does... Morevover, something is strange : the figure is not in the pdf as it should be, but the corresponding space is left empty...

Comment: I didn't say they should to be in the *same* directory, but that the `.eps` should be in the *current* directory for the command line compilation. Also, latex normally reads the `.eps` file for the size information. So if space was left, it means the `.eps` file is in the TeX input path but not necessarily in the current directory (of the command line).

Comment: Excuse me for my mistake, but I think that is not the problem although, because I run the command line in the directory where both my Exemple.tex and my .eps files are. And as you said, latex can read the .eps file concerning the figure size, and so the only problem is to display it in the pdf. On the contrary, TexShop can do it without any problem. Thank you for your help, one again.

Comment: xelatex can't include the eps directly. It (more precisely xdvipdfmx) has to convert it a pdf first. For this it calls in the background normally ghostscript (the exact call is declared in dvipdfmx.cfg) which writes the pdf in a temp folder. If the *same* example works in texstudio but fails on the command line then probably something is different in the environment: PATH variable, gs version, user rights, ....

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. The folder where the temp file appears, has the rights only for the root user. I think that xelatex can read the files whereas I can not access the files simply through the command line. I have not activated the root user, and I would like not to have to create one. Does anybody has a solution? Thank you! PS : changing the "var" folder to chmod 755 does't seem to work, and I wouldn't like to make something wrong with system files... PS2 : and moreover, that explanation seems the right one : xelatex can read the .eps to see the corresponding space, but not the pdf!

Comment: Well, this problem is very annoying, but I found another method : I directly import .pdf files into my latex document. It is a vector file that Illustrator can create and read without any problem, and it avoids the temporary file that xelatex can not access. Not very sexy, but that works.

Comment: Well it is certainly better to convert the file externally to a pdf: you have better control over the result and the xelatex compilation will be faster. On the other side: the folder xelatex uses for the temporary pdf files is not hard coded. xelatex uses some system information or an environment variable to identify the var folder.  So imho you should try to find out why on the command line xelatex tries to use a folder where it has no writing rights (and why this doesn't happen in texstudio).

Comment: Maybe I focused too much on the 3rd error message line, which says "Failed to read the image file: <name>.eps". But if the problem is the permissions for the `.pdf` file, this seems *very* misleading. Of course the first line says "Could not open conversion result" (i.e., the `.pdf`), but given the 3rd line, that could only mean the conversion failed because the `.eps` file couldn't be found. I would say this a bug somewhere in the code that generates these warnings.

Comment: No you are simply not reading the warnings as intended. The action starts when xdvipdfmx is trying to interpret a "PSfile="command (5. line). This triggers a chain of subactions and when either the creation or the reading of the pdf failed (1.line) the subactions reports back the failure.